# where the php directory in mac os 10.12 seirra?

Tags: php, macos

I am trying to install mcrypt extension but getting error like : grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
i noticed that php is not under /usr/include. And I am  not able to find the php directory.

Comment: try to use command to find out using `which php`

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You should ask _I'm trying too install mcrypt on a mac, but get this error DETAILS What am I doing wrong?_